# How does GitHub 'Reply by Email' work?

Tags: php, email

I notice that a lot of websites like Facebook and GitHub allow you to reply to an email notification which then posts the reply back to the application using a unique Reply-To address. How does this work on the back-end? I searched a lot but, only found that people were using unique Reply-To addresses. That's understandable but, what do they use to receive these emails? Do these companies set up email servers? I am trying to build this using PHP.

Comment: One can easily connect to and check an email account, read the contents of the emails and act accordingly. What exactly is your question here?

Answer (score 5):

A common method is to set unique message ID's in the outgoing email and then looking at the In-Reply-To header to see which email this was in reply to.  That lets you match up your server application's messaging system to emails.  For example, if you send an email that represents a help desk ticket with ID 1234, the Message-ID could be something like

ticket-1234@myserver

Then, in email clients that work nicely ([I'm looking at you Android](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2629)), when you hit Reply, the reply has the header In-Reply-To: ticket-1234@mysever.  You can go further by adding security tokens to ensure people can't forge messages (e.g. ticket-1234-hf29e9f2gf2e9fh29f@myserver).  That security token is generated on the server when you send your first message and is then confirmed in the reply.

This normally works but can cause real headaches when email clients don't behave as they should!

Comment: I came to the same conclusion as you. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75796/how-to-set-up-email-to-trigger-http-requests-when-received

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/reply_by_email.html) is how GitLab manages emails by using an identifier in the email address itself and catching it when the user replies. Although it is not relevant to any scripting language like PHP and uses server configs, this is what backend servers do to support reply by email functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up a mail server to receive mail answers.
SIEVE filters on a IMAP server could be use to make some actions when a certain filter is detected.

But you can't only use PHP to make that type of system.

Comment: Thanks Alex! What else would I need to use apart from PHP to build it? Also, what do you mean by SIEVE? Is that a tool that's inside mail servers? Any suggestion on what kind of mail server we could use?

Comment: You could use Dovecot (an IMAP server) with SIEVE ext. (see http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Sieve). SIEVE is a filter language, to filter some emails with filters like recipient email address, subject, text into email, and so on.